# Как проверить запустил ли пользователь другого бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот

Мне нужно в телеграм бота реализовать проверку запуска другого бота пользователем. То есть бот даёт пользователю ссылку на другого бота, которым я не владею, и если пользователь нажал на старт в другом боте, то продолжить чат, иначе просить дальше запустить другого бота. Надо реализовать без просьбы пользователя переслать сообщение от бота и без групп или каналов.

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно, если у вас нету, к примеру, доступа к бд этого бота (при условии что тот бот сразу же записывает юзера в бд)

Comment: Я не знаю, друг сказал что видел такое и то что это возможно и мне тоже показал. Возможно проверка будет осуществляться на его ботах, так что возможно я смогу получить токены ботов, или как минимум просить его в качестве аргумента когда админ бота будет добавлять ссылки на ботов для старта

Comment: Без доступа к боту получающему сообщения - не реализуемо.

Comment: Мне кажется вас ввели в заблуждение. Скорее всего это было осуществленно с двумя ботами которые пренадлежат одному разработчику. Схема напоминает аля Капчу, мудренную такую, капчу.